# Hivemq closes after some time

Tags: mqtt, iot, hivemq

I installed HiveMQ on my Ubuntu 16.04 server (dropped the zip file inside my server and unzip it) then I started it via terminal (with SSH connection) and I connected a client all was good.
Then I closed the terminal to see if I would able to connect again and I would, I could also connect after 2 hours but suddenly I couldn't.

Is there any command to use to keep it always on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this list](http://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/latest/#hivemqdocs_installation_for_specific_operating_systems) on the HiveMQ User Guide. Starting at point 10 describes, how to run HiveMQ from a run script.

> Install the init script (optional)
>
> For Debian-based linux like Debian, Ubuntu, Raspbian using init.d scripts
>
> ```
> cp /opt/hivemq/bin/init-script/hivemq-debian /etc/init.d/hivemq
> chmod +x /etc/init.d/hivemq
> ```
>
> For Debian-based linux like Debian, Ubuntu, Raspbian using systemd
>
> ```
> cp /opt/hivemq/bin/init-script/hivemq.service /etc/systemd/system/hivemq.service
> ```
>
> Modify /etc/init.d/hivemq (optional)
>
> Set the HIVEMQ_HOME and the HIVEMQ_USER variable to the correct values for your system.
>
> By default this would be:
>
> ```
> HIVEMQ_HOME=/opt/hivemq
>
> HIVEMQ_USER=hivemq
> ```
>
> If you installed HiveMQ to a different directory than /opt/hivemq please point the HIVEMQ_HOME in your init script to the correct directory. Otherwise the daemon will not start correctly.
>
> Start HiveMQ on boot (optional)
>
> For Debian-based linux like Debian, Ubuntu, Raspbian
>
> ```
> update-rc.d hivemq defaults
> ```
>
> For Debian-based linux like Debian, Ubuntu, Raspbian using systemd
>
> ```
> systemctl enable hivemq
> ```

Comment: Thank you I for sure installed it wrong I will read it carefully and I will inform you of what it happened